# Retemplate passwordbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, controltemplate

I'm working on **Windows Phone 8 C#/XAML .NET 4.5 Application** and I've been trying to retemplate/style a PasswordBox, but even though I have general idea how to do it, I can't finish it to my needs.

**PROBLEM**

The first thing I need to find is proper PasswordBox template for Windows Phone 8. I've found [this one[msdn]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334412%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), but it does not work and I don't know how to change it so it would.

**QUESTION**

- **Is this template the right one? How to change it so it would "stick"?**

Comment: You can change all you want when you edit template you know?(right click on your control) Use blend will be more easy :)

Comment: got it, if you write it as an answer, i'll give you +1 and correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you getting failed?  What errors you are getting while working on it.

The following is the Windows Phone 8 PasswordBox style . I created using Expression Blend.

```
<Style x:Key="PasswordBoxStyle" TargetType="PasswordBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="PasswordBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="EnabledBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <Border x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhonePasswordBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <PasswordBox x:Name="DisabledContent" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" Password="{TemplateBinding Password}" PasswordChar="{TemplateBinding PasswordChar}" Template="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledPasswordBoxTemplate}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Well, I'm a bit of a newbie to WPF & Windows Phone, so I didn't know much about styling, not to mention where to get the template. Thanks for the answer. I got pretty much the same one a bit earlier from a comment and found aout a way to get this template where i need it using visual studio. :)

Comment: This one is good for practicing http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/custom-styles-and-templates-in-windows-phone-intro